# How to I send messages from Windows Phone to Service Bus using AMQP?

Tags: windows-phone-8, amqp, azureservicebus

I am building an Internet of Things service that is intended to support multiple clients, including smart phones and dumber custom devices. I have been evaluating using MQTT as well as AMQP.

In building a client on Windows Phone, it seems that there is no library that supports service bus over AMQP. It seems that Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging does not run on Windows Phone, and  [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.aspx) (which runs on Windows RT and Windows Phone) does not do AMQP.

I get that there are other alternatives (such as using http), but my goal is a single endpoint across many devices. It seems that I can use [Apache Qpid Proton](http://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) to send AMQP on iOS and Android devices, but there is nothing for Windows Phone.

Is there a library out there for AMQP on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

The better approach in my opinion would be to use azure mobile services. Azure mobile services give REST endpoint which any client can work with. Then from Azure Mobile services you can push the messages to Service bus so you can scale your service. The sample in [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Enqueue-and-Dequeue-e9429caa) would give you some idea as how you shall do it